# custom master page, content coming after footer

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage, branding

I have created a HTML page using bootstrap and custom CSS. Assigned it as SharePoint master page but the SharePoint content is coming below the footer.  Below are the HTML code, I used.

I am new to designing as well as SharePoint

```
<title>Master Page</title>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<header>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="site-name">
            <h1>sitename</h1>       
        </div>
    </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mynavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</header>

<footer>
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <div class="site-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="block col-md-2 col-sm-6"></div>
                    <div class="block col-md-2 col-sm-6"></div>
                    <div class="block col-md-2 col-sm-6"></div>
                    <div class="block col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="block col-md-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="copy-right">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        CopyRights(c)
                        <a href="#">www.abc.com</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I gues u didn't copy your seatlle.master from SP and changed it. In the default masterpage of SharePoint are different placeholders for such as content, header, menus etc. Try to copy the default masterpage and change it the way you like.

Comment: tip - place your `<footer>` tag just above the closing body tag `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

you please check where are this tags in your master page. this tags should be align with your design `<div id="s4-workspace">   <div id="s4-bodyContainer">`

and `<div data-name="ContentPlaceHolderMain">` this should place your sharepoint content. please check below the modified html

```
<div data-name="ContentPlaceHolderMain"> <div class="site-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="block col-md-2 col-sm-6"></div>
                    <div class="block col-md-2 col-sm-6"></div>
                    <div class="block col-md-2 col-sm-6"></div>
                    <div class="block col-md-3"></div>
                    <div class="block col-md-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```